# JSF and Richfaces on JBoss AS 4

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, richfaces

I need to develop a presentation layer for an existing Java EE application running on JBoss AS 4.2.1.GA. I have been reading on JSF, Facelets and RichFaces and tried a few examples - some things worked but others didn't because of the limitations of library versions I used, considering the outdated JBoss.

Can someone recommend the direction I need to be heading to get this done as quickly as possible by using the mentioned server? By this I mean the Eclipse tool (WTP, JBoss Tools, ...), type of project, dependencies, ... Also, to shorten development time, maybe also use JRebel?
I know I would be better off using the latest server, but unfortunately it is not an option.

Also, I have installed JBoss Tools for Eclipse Indigo, but for creating RichFaces Project, it requires JBoss EAP 6 or AS 7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had created applications using JSF 1.2, RichFaces 3.3.3, JBoss Seam 2.0.2 (not required) for JBoss AS 4.2.2.GA. For development was used Eclipse (3.4/3.5) IDE for Java EE Developers. Version of Eclipse is not important. Yes, you need WTP. In my projects seam-gen was used for generating project skeleton. If you don't use Seam you can create Web project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you also please tell me how you did application deployment - I am building (using Maven) after every change, and then copying to JBoss deployment folder. If I do "Run on server" from Eclipse, pages don't look completely ok.

Comment: I my projects Ant was used for build. Deployment on local server and hot deployment worked without any problem. With Maven it should work exact the same. Check if some jar missing in your local environment, but exists on the server (shared for more apps). Other case: you have deployed 2 applications with different versions of the jar (same name but different versions) - this conflict is reflected in log.

Comment: There is no issue with deployment, just that pages don't load completely the same, e.g. jsflot chart is missing. Thanks in any case.